# Can I show fingers on Screencast for Android remote debugging in Chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, remote-debugging, developer-tools

I'm working on touch events in Android webview and will give a presentation. Is there a way for me to show fingers on screencast in Developer Tools? So that my audience can see where my fingers are on the screen.
[image]

Comment: In the end, I open the "Show touches" and "Pointer location" in Android developer options. And use Vysor to show the screen.